# How can we capture a mouse event when it's already out of the client area?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, mouseevent

I have an application that has a list of buttons and has customized tooltips. Whenever the mouse hovers through the buttons, the tooltips come out and is working fine. However, I want to hide the tooltips when the mouse cursor is outside the client area. How can I tell my application that the mouse is already out of the client area, when the mouse events I have are limited to the client area alone?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use GetCapture(), that's what I always do.

Answer (score 3):

You use [TrackMouseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646265(VS.85).aspx), this will send you a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message when the mouse leaves your window.